# Accessing UserDefaults in viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

When accessing `UserDefaults` I have always been under the impression that doing so in `viewDidLoad()` is a bad practice and could result in a crash. Hence meaning I have accessed `UserDefaults` in `viewDidAppear()`.
Looking around the internet, it seems that people access it from `viewDidLoad()`.

Is accessing `UserDefaults` from `viewDidLoad()` absolutely fine? If so, are there any exceptions or any suggestions as to why I may under this impression?

Comment: It's fine. viewDidLoad is simply a method that gets called when a view controller is loaded.

Comment: Yes. You can access it. The issue you have experience maybe due to some other reason. Could please share some code, so that we can understand

Comment: Using it from `UserDefaults` is absolutely fine even there could be N of use cases where we have to use it from `viewDidLoad` @user13583757

Comment: It can be bad only if you will at every viewDidLoad get ~20MB image from UserDefaults)))

Answer (score 1):

> Is accessing UserDefaults from viewDidLoad() absolutely fine?

Yes. I have no idea how you've picked up the idea that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is absolutely fine accessing the `UserDefaults` from `viewDidLoad` nothing wrong with this.
Even, there could be **N** number of use cases where we require to use it from `viewDidLoad`. For example, configure UI or take decision-based on that stored (in user defaults) information.

[More about user defaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)